# Unable to run jar file. (Error: Could not find or load main class co.pissarra.Mainkt)

Tags: gradle, jar, kotlin, build.gradle

I was trying to create a small webserver using spark and kotlin.

But I am stuck at the step where I should be able to create a jar of the project and run it from the command line. But I get the following error on running `java -jar pissarra-core-all-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar`

`Error: Could not find or load main class co.pissarra.Mainkt`

I tried using intellij idea's artifact creation without success, and moved on to creating jar using `build.gradle`. Following is the code for the same

```
task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Version': version,
                'Main-Class': 'co.pissarra.Mainkt'
    }
    baseName = project.name + '-all'
    from { configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}
```

After running `./gradlew clean` followed by `./gradlew fatJar`, I am able to create jar file in `build/libs/` directory. This jar also gives the same error.

On extracting the jar file, I am able to see the directory structure `co/pissarra/` with the `Mainkt.class` file inside it. Also it has the `META-INF` directory with `MANIFEST.MF` file whose content are as follows

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Version: 1.0-SNAPSHOT
Main-Class: co.pissarra.Mainkt
```

Since stackoverflow does not allows to upload files, you can find the jar file [here](https://files.fm/u/5bccckk5). You can also build the jar file from the github project [here](https://github.com/pr-gupta/Pissarra).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your MANIFEST file. The class name should be "MainKt" and not "Mainkt"

Comment: Yeah.. Silly mistake. Was solving it by using java file for Main class instead of using kotlin. Thanks a ton.